# Number of primes in the sequence $1, 2, 3, \dots, 2^n$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Suppose $n$ and $k$ are positive integers such that $2^n > (n+1)^k$.

> Show that there are at least $k$ prime numbers in the sequence $1, 2, 3,  \dots, 2^n$.

Could you please give me some hints where to start. How can I use the assumption on $n$ and $k$?

Comment: how could the number $$2^n$$ with $$n>2$$ be a prime?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner where on earth in the question did you read that anyone was claiming $2^n$ is prime?

Comment: ok,ok, i haven't seen the number $3$, pardon

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner because it wasn't there yet :)

Comment: Ah, I see... It *would* be reasonable to assume $1,2,... 2^n$ was the powers of $2$.  My apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof of Lemma 0.3 in [these notes by A.J. Hildebrand](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~hildebr/ant/main0.pdf) does exactly that.
Compressed proof: Call $p_1, \ldots,p_l$ the primes below $2^n$. We want $l\geq k$. Use unique factorization in $\mathbb Z$ to write every integer less than $2^n$ as a product $\prod p_i^{a_i}$. The upper bound $a_i \leq \log(2^n)/\log p_i\leq n$ implies that each $a_i$ can take at most $n+1$ values. So we have at most $(n+1)^l$ integers below $2^n$. Thus $(n+1)^l\geq 2^n$. Thus $l>k$.

Comment: Wow, that's beautiful. Thanks!